# clicking link inside div causes fadeOut instead of following link

Tags: jquery

I wrote this code and am very new to both Javascript and jQuery so I am having quite the fun.  Basically I've narrowed down to when a link is clicked my DIV box will perform fadeOut() before following the link.  I've been search SO for a few days and have not been able to either convert a response or found one that works.

I've tried to keep the code clean and added some CSS to it so people can see it and modify it based on the answer/solutions given.

http://jsfiddle.net/dUTex/

//click the element with the class ".exp"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".exp").click(function() {
    $('.expMenuWrapper').fadeIn("fast");
    $('.expMenu').fadeIn("fast");
});
```

//This is where Im getting snapped up at, I borrowed this and its not working correctly.  it fades out before the link gets its "action"

```
$(".close-btn, .expMenu").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.expMenuWrapper').fadeOut("fast");
});
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The `preventDefault` is preventing the default behavior of the click.

I suggest to read [this](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

So, to fadeout & follow the link, your code should look like:

```
$(".close-btn, .expMenu").click(
   function(e) {
      $('.expMenuWrapper').fadeOut("fast");
   });
});
```

Should you wish parent components not to receive the click event, use [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

If you want to stop any other listener from being invoked (even on the same element), use [`stopImmediatePropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/). All available on the [`event` object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

Answer (score 0):

Using `preventDefault` you are telling the browser not to do whatever it normally does. You are doing this to all the links in the menu. You should prevent only on the closing-button, like this:

```
$(".close-btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.expMenuWrapper').fadeOut("fast");
});
```

EDIT: Following Matyas's answer may cause some unpredicted behavor. The close-button is a link with a `#` as it's `href`. Not preventing default will make the screen jump to the top (if you have scrolled down a bit, you will suddenly jump to the top of the page), and there will be added a hash in your url. This is not good use of javascript. If you have a "link" that is not really a link, use prevent.